# Make Adobe Acrobat Reader DC default PDF application ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have recently installed Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2020.013.20064 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I installed it following these instructions: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/06/11/step-by-step-acrobat-reader-dc-windows-ubuntu-20-04-installation/

How do I make Adobe Acrobat Reader DC my default PDF application. I have tried changing it in the properties section, but the application doesn't appear in the list. How do I solve it?

Comment: **That is not recommended.** (For security reasons) You are better off using the inbuilt PDF view/print capabilities within **Firefox** (for online), and the (inbuilt) '**Document Viewer**' for local PDF files. For *special conditions* (Adobe specific, interactive), then use 'Acrobat Reader' (snap acrordrdc) by using "Open With Other .."